# How to set http2 for a specific location block inside nginx configuration file

Tags: http, nginx, location, h2

Question related to `proxy_http_version` in nginx

I have multiple location blocks inside my server block and I want to set h2 protocol on certain locations.

Ex: nginx location block which is inside a server block which has multiple location blocks is placed below.

````
location ~^/app$|^.*\.(js|css|woff|ttf)$ {
        proxy_cache eggstatic;
        expires 1d;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1; // want to change this to h2
    
        proxy_pass https:site_id;
    }
    ```
````